# unable to initialize global.run when using multi threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

I'm using scala 2.12.2 and am importing a package scala.tools.nsc.Global. I've the below piece of code that works fine when working with a single thread or multiple threads working sequentially. however, when I have multiple threads and try to execute this piece of code concurrently, I get a null exception. could you please help me with this?

```
  val compiler = new global.Run
  ClassloaderCache.setCompiledFile(compiler.compileSources(sourceFiles))
```

on debugging deep, I understand the code breaks Definitions.scala and while executing the line ObjectClass.initialize in the below method.

```
 // documented in JavaUniverse.init
    def init() {
      if (isInitialized) return
      ObjectClass.initialize
      ScalaPackageClass.initialize
      symbolsNotPresentInBytecode
      NoSymbol
      isInitialized = true
    } //init
```

Comment: As I recall, the Scala compiler (which is what you're digging into) isn't thread-safe (at least it wasn't in the 2.12 timeframe and not in stock form... I haven't used Hydra, however).

Comment: @LeviRamsey thanks.. so do you have any suggestions for me on how I can get around this issue? may be a version upgrade?

Comment: I don't know if later versions are thread-safe or not.  You may have to synchronize access manually.